# My VS Code is showing wrong error messages

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

[image]

Have no idea what is wrong, any thoughts and answers will be helpful. The compiler is showing errors when there aren't any.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node{
    public:
        Node * left;
        Node * right;
        int value;

        Node(int v) : value(v), left(nullptr),right(nullptr) {};

        void setLeft(Node&n){
            left = &n;
        }

        void setRight(Node&n){
            left = &n;
        }
    private:    
};

int main()
{

    Node a(10);
    Node b(20);
    Node c(30);

    a.setLeft(b);
    a.setRight(c);

    cout << a.value << endl << a.left->value << endl << a.right->value << endl << "If you read this I am working correctly!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Try the code for yourself if you believe I am in the wrong but I am not. Even now with the setters .setRight and .setLeft I still get the same errors.

Comment: Looks like there’s errors to me.

Comment: It's reporting errors correctly.  I think you want to call `setLeft` and `setRight`

Comment: [For many good reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors), don't use images of text. cut-n-paste code and error messages into the post.

Comment: @EarlyBitcoiner: As others have pointed out 1) screenshots are discouraged on SO: please copy/paste text instead.  2) The error msgs in VSCode are real.  Please confirm that  changing your code to "setLeft()", "setRight()" resolves the problem.

Comment: a pointer is not callable, your question title is **wrong**

Comment: *"Even now with the setters .setRight and .setLeft I still get the same errors."* -- Have you rebuilt the program? It seems fine to me.

Comment: It was an IntelliSense bug, restarted the program and it worked.

Comment: read your code carefully, it contains a big bug, your output should show it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`left` and `right` are variables of the class called `Node`:
`Node * left;`
`Node * Right;`

You used a variable as a function, which causes the error.

To solve the error use:
Line 30 `a.setLeft(b);`
Line 31 `a.setRight(c);`

Also, on line 18, you’re trying to setRight() but you change the variable of `left`.
It must be `right = &n`.